# Why vxlan tunnel disappear after ifdown bond?

Tags: 16.04, networking, kernel, tunnel, network-bonding

I created a vxlan tunnel using the iprouter2 tool. The command was:

```
ip link add vxlan2 type vxlan id 2 group 233.1.1.1 dev bond0 dstport 4789
```

But when I restart network or "ifdown bond0", vxlan2 disappears. It's why? There will be no such problems on CentOS.

I checked the system log and found this information:

```
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 named[2184]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 named[2184]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 named[2184]: reloading configuration succeeded
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 kernel: [ 6361.308330] bonding: bond0 is being deleted...
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 kernel: [ 6361.308609] device vxlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 kernel: [ 6361.308733] bond0 (unregistering): Released all slaves
Jul 18 11:38:04 ubuntu-22 named[2184]: any newly configured zones are now loaded
```

It seems like it was deleted by kernel. I don't want my vxlan tunnel to disappear because of "ifdown bond0". What should I do?

My Ubuntu server information is as follows:

```
root@ubuntu-22:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l
root@ubuntu-22:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-22 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

"bond0" information is as fallows:

```
root@ubuntu-22:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eno1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: ac:1f:6b:12:57:b4
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eno2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: ac:1f:6b:12:57:b5
Slave queue ID: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the source code of ifupdown to find out the reason. I found that the "/etc/network/if-post-down.d/ifenslave" script was invoked using "/bin/run-parts" when "iface_postdown". At the end of the script, the program will remove the master itself:

```
# Remove the master itself
echo "-$IFACE" > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters
rm /run/network/ifenslave.$IFACE
```

When I comment out "echo "-$IFACE" > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters", bond0 will not be deleted.